# In C#, how to check if a property of an object in a List<> contains a string?

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say I have an object like:

```
class Thing {
  string Id;
  string Name;
  string Message;
}
```

and a `List<Thing>`. Before I add a `new Thing` to the list, I want to check to make sure the list doesn't already contain the thing, but I don't have a purely identical thing to compare with (so can't do `list.Contains(Thing)`, but I want to do something like that)

The Thing.Message property could be the same, but other properties different.

How can I check the `List<Thing>` to see if it contains a `Thing` which has a .Message property equal to a specific string?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a `Dictionary<string, Thing>` instead of a List

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linq!

```
if (myList.Any(t => t.Message == "hello"))
```

Comment: He actually wants the opposite for his if statement, which could either be written as `if (!myList.Any(t => t.Message == "hello"))` or alternatively `if (myList.All(t => t.Message != "hello"))`.

Comment: Correct, but I did get what I needed from Kieren's post. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
var addedThing = new Thing {…};
if (!things.Any(t=>t.Message == addedThing.Message)) {
    things.Add(addedThing);
}
```